Append newly added files in Google drive in Google Sheets Using App Script
We are creating a library of books for the community to be displayed on our website which takes data from Google Sheets.
The books are stored in Google Drive.
What we have done: We used a Google app script available on the net which writes all documents available in the drive to google sheets. The script can be found below.
Current Problem: We have to manually run the script and once it runs it starts from the beginning and when it reaches around 800 documents or so it stops due with the message "exceed time limit"
We are looking for a Google app script to run daily at a certain time say 9 pm and when a new document is added to our drive it should update Google Sheets with that document only.(Should not start it from the begining)
There are some related links on Stack Overflow however we are looking for a unified solution
Google Apps Script trigger - run whenever a new file is added to a folder
Working Code Which currently gives the results.
function onOpen() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files/Folders')
    .addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'getListFilesandFolders')
    .addToUi();
};

function getListFilesandFolders(){
  var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderId === "") {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder ID is invalid');
    return;
  }
  makeListFilesAndFolders(folderId, true); 
};


function makeListFilesAndFolders(folderId, listAll) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sh.getRange('A2:H')
  range.clear();
  sh.appendRow(["parent","folder", "name", "date created", "URL","MimeType"]);
  try {
    var parentFolder =DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    listFiles(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName())
    listSubFolders(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName());
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

function listSubFolders(parentFolder,parent) {
  var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    Logger.log("Fold : " + childFolder.getName());
    listFiles(childFolder,parent)
    listSubFolders(childFolder,parent + "|" + childFolder.getName());
  }
};

function listFiles(fold,parent){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = [];
  var files = fold.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    data = [ 
      parent,
      fold.getName(),
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      //file.getLastUpdated(),
      file.getUrl(),       
      //file.getId(),
      //file.getSize(),
      //file.getDescription(),     
      file.getMimeType()
      ];
    sh.appendRow(data);
  }
}


The result is displayed in below format
Google Sheets after column results
We are looking for a Google app script to run daily at a certain time and when a new document is added to Google Drive it should append the details of the documents - as rows at the end of the Google Sheets. Should not start from the beginning

There are a few options: 1. You could use custom file properties/appProperties to store key/value pairs in the files and exclude them, this is advanced.  2. You could a userlabel to track the inventory and have the script add the label the first time a book is added and exclude it from future searches.   3. You could add the info in batches to the spreadsheet instead or row by row.  4. You could avoid deleting the old list and instead compare the existing list with the search results and make changes only. Including a trashed field.


You could search only for files that are created or deleted within the previous few days.  And so on.


I would keep a list of file ids in your inventory and then run a recursive routine to find if their are any new ones in any of the folders or subfolder and just add the new ones on a time based trigger. I would not us append because it's much slower that using setVallues() and load all at one time

Updating just the new files and assuming id's are stored in column A
function getNewFileIds() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("newids", "[]");
  getFileIds(DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid"));
  return JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("newids"))
}

function getFileIds(fldr) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const curids = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  var newids = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("newids"));
  let files = fldr.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let f = files.next();
    let id = f.getId();
    if (!~curids.indexOf(id)) {
      newids.push(id)
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("newids", JSON.stringify(newids));
    }
  }
  let fldrs = fldr.getFolders();
  while (fldrs.hasNext()) {
    let fdr = fldrs.next();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("newids", JSON.stringify(newids));
    getFileIds(fdr);
  }
}

function addFiles(newids) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = [];
  var idA = newids;
  idA.forEach(id => {
    let f = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
    data.push([f.getParents[0], f.getName(), f.getDateCreated(), f.getUrl(), f.getMimeType()])
  })
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}


Thanks Blindspots this point looks good: 6. You could search only for files that are created or deleted within the previous few days. Thanks Cooper for suggesting the code  When i ran it i got the error : ReferenceError: getFilesIds is not defined at getNewFileIds(Code:4:3). I have placed the folder id in Column A, as advised.  Please can you suggest how to troubleshoot the error.

Yes I had a typo in there.

Thanks Cooper for the clarification. After correcting the typo still there is another error which reads ErrorException: Invalid argument: id getNewFileIds @ Code.gs:4

The file can be found below : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nT7CUtKJf8AARRmah2qFHXm2j1-D5V8FSutLfSG0R8U/edit#gid=0
